# Why do Matplotlib documentation use numpy.arange() when range() would suffice?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, range, built-in

See the examples on this page: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Here is one example:

```py
>>> xticks(np.arange(5), ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue'))
```

Why does this example use `np.arange(5)` when `range(5)` would also work?

Is there a reason why `np.arange()` is better than `range()` here?

Comment: You can also use tuples, lists, iterators... don't interprete too much into this detail; and mind that only because the example uses one option doesn't mean it is necessarily better than any other option.

Comment: `np.arange` supports vectorization and easy manipulation (since it yields an `ndarray`) and is usually encouraged when using the datascience/numeric stack (numpy, pandas, matplotlib etc+) in general

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the benefits of numpy are practically non-existent, because each tick later on gets its own `Tick` instance anyways. In cases where efficiency matters, the input is converted to numpy arrays anyways.

Comment: One example, `np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2)`, can't be done with `range`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest _"In cases where efficiency matters, the input is converted to numpy arrays anyways."_ Wish that were true. Try timing for some suitable array `a[np.arange(1000)]` vs `a[range(1000)]`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Sorry, of course I meant "the input to **matplotlib functions** is converted [...]".

Comment: The linked docs says `array like`.  But it delegates the action to `Axes.set_xticks` which describes the input as `list`.  After several layers it appears the `ticks` goes to a `units converter`. which may be default or custom.  The `units` docs talks about arrays and array interfaces, https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/units_api.html.  It's easy to get lost in the details, but it's pretty evident that the `range` generator doesn't offer any advantages over an array created by `arange`.